# JSONDecodeError Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, django

I have a project that i am working on and I need and i am trying to send a json request. I am getting an error and i don'y know what it means in relation to the request that i am trying to send.

The following is the error:

```
JSONDecodeError at /setup_profile/
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/setup_profile/
Django Version: 1.8.6
Exception Type: JSONDecodeError
Exception Value:    
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Exception Location: C:\Users\OmarJandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\simplejson\scanner.py in _scan_once, line 118
Python Executable:  C:\Users\OmarJandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.1
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\Desktop\\opentab\\opentab',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Here is the request that I am trying to send:

```
def createUserSynapse(request):
    url = 'http://uat-api.synapsefi.com'
    headers = {
        'X-SP-GATEWAY' : 'client_id_asdfeavea561va9685e1gre5ara|client_secret_4651av5sa1edgvawegv1a6we1v5a6s51gv',
        'X-SP-USER-IP' : '127.0.0.1',
        'X-SP-USER' : '| ge85a41v8e16v1a618gea164g65',
        'Contant-Type' : 'application/json',
    }
    payload = {
        "logins":[
            {
                "email":"test@test.com",
            }
        ],
        "phone_numbers":[
            "123.456.7890",
            "test@test.com",
        ],
        "legal_names":[
            "Test name",
        ],
        "extras":{
            "supp_id":"asdfe515641e56wg",
            "cip_tag":12,
            "is_business":False,
        }
    }
    print(url)
    print(headers)
    print(payload)
    call = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
    # response = json.loads(call.text)
    call = call.json()
    print (call)
    print(call.content)
    return render(request, 'tabs/create_user_synapse.html', call)
```

Here is the traceback, I think the error is going to be where the call = call.json() command is or the line above it with the actual response

```
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

C:\Users\OmarJandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in get_response
                                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\OmarJandali\Desktop\opentab\opentab\tab\views.py in profileSetup
                            createUserSynapse(request) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\OmarJandali\Desktop\opentab\opentab\tab\views.py in createUserSynapse
                call = call.json() ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\OmarJandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py in json
                    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\OmarJandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\simplejson\__init__.py in loads
                    return _default_decoder.decode(s) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\OmarJandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py in decode
                    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\OmarJandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py in raw_decode
                    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end()) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\OmarJandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\simplejson\scanner.py in scan_once
                        return _scan_once(string, idx) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\OmarJandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\simplejson\scanner.py in _scan_once
                        raise JSONDecodeError(errmsg, string, idx) ...
▶ Local vars
```

Comment: I don't know whether this is the problem, but your "Constant-type" header name is misspelled.

Comment: Where's you traceback? It's not clear where in your code this error is happening. [mcve]

Comment: I will add the traceback in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your post request return b'Running!' which couldn't be converted to json. so line : call = call.json() raise JSONDecodeError error.

Comment: so when i comment out the line of code i get this issue `ValueError at /setup_profile/
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 8; 2 is required
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/setup_profile/
Django Version: 1.8.6
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: 
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 8; 2 is required
Exception Location: C:\Users\OmarJandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py in __init__, line 20`

Comment: render method expecting dictionary and you're providing "call" which is not dict.

Answer (score 1):

The basic issue is that your call to the API appears not to be returning a response that has valid JSON so that when you call that method, `requests` fails to parse it, like Muktadiur said.

In order to diagnose this, you need to figure out what is getting returend, i.e. is it a failed response or in a format you're not expecting from the API (so maybe the `content-type` typo is causing the API to return differently than you expect, for example).

It might be worthwhile to run the requests code in an interactive python session, ping the API as you do in the Django view, and see what you're actually getting back. I'd suggest `curl` to do that a bit more easily but I see you're in a Win environment.

Edit: Actually, the easiest way to diagnose this might be for you to move call to `print(call.content)` above the problematic call to json. You should also probably add `print(call.status_code)`. That should quickly show you 1) What you're actually getting back and 2) What HTTP status code you're getting back. That should help dx what's going screwy with the API call.

Comment: how do i go about running the request in an interactive python session. I have a local host version running live on my machine with django. Also can i get rid of the json and headers for the request.. would that do anything....

Comment: i got rid of the headers and payload as wellas the paload and headers in the resquest.. i am getting the same error message... that is the only place i can think that is giving me the issue, if that is not it, what could it be....

Comment: what is the best way to send a json request in django that lets me pass the header and content... Liek format wise, because i looked online and couldnt find the proper way to send and receive a json request in django

Comment: I'm going to amend my comment having seen your code a bit more.